# How to get values from Liferay authentication Page?

Tags: jsp, authentication, jboss, liferay, roles

Good Morning everybody :)

I would like to have your opinions and help in that case :

I would like to detect the current user loggin Liferay Portal, retrieve his role and according to the role, I want redirect the user to the appropriate JSP page.

Is there any code or any solution that can help me do that ? Thank you and have a nice day ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First by JSP page I believe that you are talking to Liferay Page like web/guest/home, since redirecting to jsp makes no sense in context of portal. Second I assume you want this action post login, that is as soon as you login, you want to detect a user and check his role and based on his role redirect to a Liferay Page.

If that is the question, then yes you can do it. You have to create a [Login Post Event](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Customizing+the+default+page+after+login#section-Customizing+the+default+page+after+login-DefaultLandingPageAction.java) hook and redirect to the page. You can get the logged in user information user

```
PortalUtil.getUserId(request)
```

You can get Roles of a user similarly by using Liferay's API like **user.getRoles()** will return all the regular roles of a user

Redirecting to a page is mentioned in the Link that I gave above. If you have Liferay src then just see DefaultLandingPageAction as to how to redirect user to a particular page post login.

Comment: "First by JSP page I believe that you are talking to Liferay Page like web/guest/home, since redirecting to jsp makes no sense in context of portal" you're right but I meant by "JSP page" a web application, seen as a portlet in Liferay.